# Multiple and Separate Mail Functions PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

Is my `$headers` and or second `mail()` function incorrect or improper? My page has a form that when you fill out will send an email to the recipient, then a second one to via a text message (many carriers has a text to email feature). When I submitted the form the first `mail()` function works, **but the second one doesn't.** Any ideas? Also, I'm doing this because I want it to send an email and a text message (I thought this was a great idea) so that the recipient is notified that there's an email that needs his/her attention.

Here's what I mean.

```
// HTML FORM here, collects just name, email, subject line, message
// When the form is submitted it does this...

          $to = "recepient@email.com";
          $to_sms = "recepienttextnumber@tmomail.net";
          $subject = filter_var($_POST['subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)." - FORM";
          $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
         'Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
             'From: noreply@email.com' . "\r\n" .
                     'Reply-To: info@email.com' . "\r\n" .
                     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
          $body = "
          <html>
          <p>This is an automatic email notification. <strong>Please do not reply to this email</strong></p>
          <p>You received a message from ". $name . " that needs your attention ASAP.!</p>
          <p>Client name: ".$name."<br />
          Client phone: ".$phone."<br />
          Email: ".$email."<br />
          About: ".$_POST['subject']."<br />
          Message: ".$message."</p>
          </html>";
          $body_sms = "Great news! ".$name." has contacted you via the FORM. Check your email now.";

          // Send Email & Text Notification
                      //Here sends out the form via email
          mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
                      //alternatively a second message is sent to another 
          mail($to_sms, $subject, $body_sms, "From: FORM");


//Echos a thank you.
```

Comment: I suggest you make a copy of your `$headers` and name it `$headers2` and use `mail($to, $subject, $body_sms, $headers2);` that may be the problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii- that works... please make it so that I can credit your answer etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make a copy of your `$headers` and name it `$headers2` and use

```
mail($to, $subject, $body_sms, $headers2);
```

that may be the problem.